# Number of non negative integer solutions of $2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10 (x_i \ge 0)$

Tags: combinatorics

This is the equation

$2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10  (x_i \ge 0)$

when $x_i$s have no coefficient it is easy but I don't know how to solve it when there is coefficient. Besides that I would be appreciated if you solve this problem without generating function (if it is possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating functions really aren't so bad!  Letting $[x^n]$ denote the operator which extracts the $x^n$ coefficient of something, the number we want is
$$ [x^{10}]\frac1{(1-x^2)^2}\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$
Multiply the top and bottom by $(1+x)^2$ to get a simpler denominator:
$$[x^{10}]\frac{(1+x)^2}{(1-x^2)^4}$$
Now expand the denominator as a series and multiply out the numerator; as the numerator has $3$ terms we get $3$ coefficients from the series (the middle one turns out to be zero):
$$
 \begin{align}
 &[x^{10}](1+2x+x^2)\sum_{k\ge0} (-1)^k\binom{-4}k x^{2k}\\
 &=([x^{10}]+2[x^9]+[x^8])\sum_{k\ge0} (-1)^k\binom{-4}k x^{2k}\\
 &=\binom{-4}{4}+2(0)-\binom{-4}{5}\\
 &=\binom74+\binom85 = 91.
\end{align}
$$

With hindsight, you can see this agrees with Ahmed's solution.  If $x_3$ and $x_4$ are both even, say $x_3=2y_3$ and $x_4=2y_4$, you're really solving $x_1+x_2+y_3+y_4=5$; there are $\binom85$ solutions (e.g. by "stars and bars").  If $x_3$ and $x_4$ are both odd, say $x_3=2y_3+1$ and $x_4=2y_4+1$, you're solving $x_1+x_2+y_3+y_4=4$, which has $\binom74$ solutions.

Comment: I tried to find out how did you reason your answer specially this one $$\begin{align}
  [x^{10}]\frac1{(1-x^2)^2}\frac1{(1-x)^2}
 &=[x^{10}]\frac{(1+x)^2}{(1-x^2)^4}\\
\end{align}
$$ 

but I failed! would you please explain a bit more in your answer or at least show the steps!

Comment: I added some more detail - hope that helps!

Comment: If the equation was $2x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4 = 10$ then the generating function was $$ [x^{10}]\frac1{(1-x^2)^2}\frac1{(1-x)}\frac1{(1-x^3)}.$$ Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Both $x_3$ and $x_4$ are even or both are odd. Take each case.

Comment: ok fine, then what should I do with $2$ coefficient?

Comment: Divide everything by $2$.